# Is it possible to know how many bytes where written or read when using the BIO_read() and BIO_write() functions?

Tags: sockets, networking, count, openssl

For accounting purposes (and, especially, to throttle a TCP connection), I'd like to know how many bytes travel through a given socket.

When using a plain socket, that's very easy. When using TLS encryption, I just noticed that I don't seem to have access to the number of bytes being transferred through the socket. Or maybe there is a function that has that info and I don't know about it?

Looking at the `BIO_read()` and `BIO_write()`, it only returns the number of decrypted bytes traveling. Not the actual number of bytes going through the socket.

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/BIO_write.html

The `BIO_read_ex()` and `BIO_write_ex()` really only change how the number of bytes is returned to the caller. Nothing about the total number of bytes transferred over the socket. Also with TLS encryption, a `BIO_read()` may write data and vice versa.

The only thing that I think would work is for me to add a set of methods in between the TLS methods and the fd (socket) methods, with the `BIO_meth_...()` functions/structures, etc. Is that really the only way to gather that information? Or did I miss something?

Comment: I don't think that you have this kind of statistics easily accessible. But if you use a memory BIO instead of a socket BIO you have full control over the data after the TLS encapsulation.